# List of figures doesn't look like other sections in komacv class

Tags: koma-script

I am using [komacv](http://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/komacv/komacv.pdf) class to typeset my CV and [pdfpages](http://mirror.switch.ch/ftp/mirror/tex/macros/latex/contrib/pdfpages/pdfpages.pdf) to attach scans of my university transcripts etc. to the end of file. I want to have a list of attachments before the attachments section. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{komacv}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\renewcommand*\listfigurename{Attachments}

\begin{document}

\section{Some section}
\section{Some other section}
\listoffigures

\includepdfset{
pages={-}, 
width=\textwidth
}
\includepdf[addtolist={1, figure, {some document}, doc:1}]{doc.pdf}
\end{document}
```

I get the following output (instead of an asterisk, "Attachments" should be in the section title):

[image]

Could anyone say what's gone wrong? Other automatically created sections, such as bibliography, get their name and style from komacv without any trouble.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The obvious answer is that `komacv` doesn't really support `\listoffigures`. But I think something can be done.

Answer (score 2):

You have to tell `komacv` that the list of attachments is a numbered section.

```
\documentclass[]{komacv}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\setuptoc{lof}{numbered}

\begin{document}

\section{Some section}
\section{Some other section}
\listoftoc[Attachments]{lof}

\includepdfset{
pages={-},
width=\textwidth
}
\includepdf[addtolist={1, figure, {some document}, doc:1}]{example-image.pdf}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for such a prompt answer! However, when I copied and pasted the same code, I got a weird result: an '[' in the section title and a doubled 'Attachments]Attachments' before the list.

Answer (score 0):

I would just redefine `\section*` to mean `\section`.

Code:

```
\let\oldsection\section
\makeatletter
\def\section{%
\@ifstar{\@nonStarred}{\@nonStarred}%
}
%\def\@Starred{%
%\@ifnextchar[%
%{\GenericWarning{}{Warning: A starred chapter can not have parameters. I am %going to ignore them!}\@StarredWith}%
%{\@StarredWithout}%
%}      
%\def\@StarredWith[#1]#2{%
%\oldsection{#2}
%}
%\def\@StarredWithout#1{%
%\oldsection*{#1}%
%}
\def\@nonStarred{%
\@ifnextchar[%
{\@nonStarredWith}%
{\@nonStarredWithout}%
}
\def\@nonStarredWith[#1]#2{%
\oldsection[#1]{#2}%
}
\def\@nonStarredWithout#1{%
\oldsection{#1}%
}
\makeatother
```

not tested but I suppose it could work.

Comment: Thank you, it really worked. I still do not fully understand, what the problem was, but well...

Comment: @dareia The star on your picrure made me think that your class doesnt accept srarred sections... so I redefined star section to mean section... This way can handle any stareed section like toc or lof oe lot etc